# missing libssl.so.10 when install postgresql92-server postgresql92-contrib

Tags: linux, postgresql-9.2, libssl, libcrypto

when I install postgresql92-server postgresql92-contrib I met some problem ,the details as below
[image: error message]

but I can find the libs

[image: libs]

my linux release as below 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

found similar thing here. You can give it a try:

https://opensourcedbms.com/dbms/installing-postgresql-9-2-on-cent-os-6-3-redhat-el6-fedora/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<include the location to the openssl lib folder>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```